# Setting up a VPN with rules who can connect with who

Tags: ubuntu, vpn, firewall, routing

For delivering updates and support on software I've been working on I have been thinking about setting up a VPN server. The idea would be that the clients are constantly connected but only the traffic that has to go through the vpn would go through the VPN. I know this can be achieved client side but I would like to enforce this server side as well.

For security reasons I would like to make sure that on the vpn the customers can only connect with me (Remote desktop/FTP/Windows shares) and not with eachother.

Is there anyone who can confirm that this is a viable option and with what software this could be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

With OpenVPN, you can choose which routes will be sent over the VPN and which routes will be local-only; for instance, you can set only things going to your machine, or your subnet, etc will route through the VPN, but all other traffic will flow as normal.  This should be configurable on the server side.

[Here's](https://community.openvpn.net/openvpn/wiki/RoutedLans) an example that you can adapt for your needs, with the understanding that if you just wanted to route traffic to ONE machine instead of ALL machines on a subnet, you could use a netmask of 255.255.255.255 instead of 255.255.255.0.  There are myriad other documents online explaining how to get an OpenVPN setup that will work for you, you just need to decide how you want it to run (ie. in a hardware appliance standalone, as part of your router, etc).

[Here](https://openvpn.net/index.php/access-server/docs/quick-start-guide.html) is a quick start guide.  And yes, to affirm, what you desire is easily configurable.  Good luck!